# Updating 10% of table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm looking at a 2.8 million record table and trying to find a way to efficiently update a column labeled 'Control' with "x" randomly for 10% of the records in MySQL.

One method is to create a separate table with the select:

> select * from table order by rand() < 0.10

and then update my original table by referencing the new smaller table, but I wanted to know if there was a simpler/quicker way.

Comment: Using `RAND()` without a `WHERE` on a 2.8 million record table is never a great idea..

Comment: @RaymondNijland what would you recommend instead?

Comment: Can you post the table structure? Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE table`

Comment: @RaymondNijland That didn't quite work. What is your question exactly?

Comment: "That didn't quite work. What is your question exactly?" The CREATE TABLE which was used to create the table.. You need to replace table in `SHOW CREATE TABLE table` with your real table name the query should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
UPDATE MyTable SET control='x' WHERE RAND() < 0.10;
```

The condition in the WHERE clause will be true on approximately 10% of the rows.

This way you don't need to make a copy of your table.

---

By the way, this is not necessary to use the SELECT since you can update 10% of your table in place, but for what it's worth, your SELECT that you proposed in your question would not do what you think it would. You probably think it does what the following would do:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE RAND() < 0.10;
```

Or alternatively:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT ?
```

Where the parameter is a number equal to 1/10th the number of rows in the table.

Comment: @RaymondNijland That right, it does a table-scan, because it's an expression that cannot narrow down the search by using any index. It will take a while to run the UPDATE.

Comment: Yes i also think your query is the best method +1.. i was thinking about writing a SQL number generator with `RAND() < 0.10` in a delivered table and JOIN those numbers with the table on a primary id where `RAND() < 0.10 is true`.. But that doesn't work completely correct when the id column has gaps.. Besides `UNION` (used in the number generator) would force MySQL into using a internal memory temporary table which can and up running on disk with 28 million records.. Also `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` to limit the number generator would also have trigger a full scan on the InnoDB engine.

Comment: Yeah, better to keep it simple, especially if this is a one-time UPDATE. The time it takes to engineer some advanced solution is not worth it, unless the task has to be done optimally many times.

Comment: @RaymondNijland . . . Scanning the entire table is the least of the performance concerns when you are updating 10% of the data.  All the pages will be read -- and dirty -- in all likelihood.